# Using the HTML5 attribute draggable="true" allow the page to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the HTML5 attribute `draggable="true"` on some of my div's on my webpage. I want it so that when you drag one of these items to the bottom of the page, it scrolls the page down and when you drag it to the top, it scrolls the page up.

*On Chrome*, it automatically lets me scroll down when I drag to the bottom, but not up. On Firefox, it doesn't automatically let me scroll in either direction. Any help?

Please refer the below code :

```
var stop = true;
$(".draggable").on("drag", function (e) {

    stop = true;

    if (e.originalEvent.clientY < 150) {
        stop = false;
        scroll(-1)
    }

    if (e.originalEvent.clientY > ($(window).height() - 150)) {
        stop = false;
        scroll(1)
    }

});

$(".draggable").on("dragend", function (e) {
     stop = true;
});

var scroll = function (step) {
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollY + step);
    if (!stop) {
        setTimeout(function () { scroll(step) }, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: `.draggable` != `[draggable]`, and you can't customize the browser's auto-scroll functionality, afaik.

Comment: Any alternative for this?